# Directory Specific url rewriting in IIS ColdFusion

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, coldfusion

I have site 
`http://example.com/school/student.cfm?id=100`

Also, i have another link `http://example.com/collage/student.cfm?id=200`

I want to write a URL rewrite rule which always re-write the `http://example.com/school/student.cfm?id=100`
to `http://example.com/school/student/100`

and

`http://example.com/collage/student.cfm?id=200`
to `http://example.com/collage/student/200`

I have written rule like this but that will always use 1 directory, But I want this to be working for all directories.

```
<rule name="Redirect to school with ONE parameter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*/([^/]+)/?$" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="school/student.cfm?id_Name={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. The range of solution goes from - only rewriting school and collage - to rewriting any path that ends with student - to using a generic pattern that rewrites everything.

To give you an idea how to do that with IIS' regexp:

```
<match url="^(collage|school)/student/([0-9]+)/?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/student.cfm?id={R:2}" />

<match url="^([^/]+)/student/([0-9]+)/?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/student.cfm?id={R:2}" />

<match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:2}.cfm?id={R:3}" />
```

Comment: Great work like a charm. It solve my problem. Bundle of Thanks :)